# How to save the activity history in opportunity in custom button click?

Tags: salesforce

I Have two button in opportunity page one is "Save" which is by default and other is custom button "Send Confirmation"

When user click in the "Save" button the activity history is save(dont how it happen)

Same functionality is needed on custom button click.

Any body have any idea..plz help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity history tracks completed tasks and emails. It occurs deep below at database level and has nothing to do with buttons per se. When you say that Activity history is updated on save, how is it updated? Do you have a trigger in the background that sends an email or creates a completed task?

Comment: i correct that it not update it save activity histroy on custom button click

Comment: i still dont understand you, saves what in activity history?

Comment: ..please let me know how the Activity history works and what data save there.bcuse may be i am thinking in wrong direction